# Mostrar variables Javascript en HTML

Tags: html

he hecho lo que decian con el metodo .innerHTML. El codigo lo implemento igual pero no logro que funcione. Mi codigo es el siguiente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var fecha = new Date(fecha);
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var mes = fecha.getMonth();
var ano = fecha.getFullYear();
var fechacompleta = hola amigos;  // dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;
var objetivo = document.getElementById('texto_nav1').innerHTML;
objetivo.innerHTML = fechacompleta;
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <label id="texto_nav1"></label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores.  La variable `objetivo` debe de referirse al objeto mismo, no al `innerHTML`.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```js
var fecha = new Date();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
var ano = fecha.getFullYear();
var fechacompleta = dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;
var objetivo = document.getElementById('texto_nav1');
objetivo.innerHTML = fechacompleta;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
       
</head>
<body>
    <label id="texto_nav1"></label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si pero en esa solucion donde usa el javascript?